# How to take click on action bar icon in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I added the Notification icon on action bar. I want to take clicked on it. So how can i do this? Anyone knows please revert back with answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you added a toolbar item you can do it like this:

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Action Name", "Icon.png", async () =>
{
    //Your code on clicked
}));
```

To do it in Xaml, you need to add the command attribute:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Invite" Command="{Binding ToolbarItemCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Then in your code behind define an ICommand named ToolbarItemCommand which will be triggered when the icon is clicked

Comment: i added toolbar icon in xaml like <ToolbarItem.Icon>. So is there any way to give clicked on xaml and writing implementation in code behind file(.cs)

Comment: I updated my answer. I think that should work but I'm not at a computer that I can test it on rn so you'll have to let me know. Hope it helps!

Comment: I solved this like this way.  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="TopBarOptionmenu" Order="Primary" Clicked="notifyClicked">
      <ToolbarItem.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="notif.png" />
      </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

Comment: @sid I'd accept cvanbeek's answer as the solution since it's correct. You should use the Command instead of Clicked event handler. When you use event handlers, you have a tight coupling between your UI and code behind. With commands you'll have lose coupling and it'll be easy to test the UI and code behind separately. Take a look at the following article for more information: https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/